# C++: Variable 'DiscreteGBM::S0' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6)

Tags: c++

I have an error message C++: Variable 'DiscreteGBM::S0' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). This message is repeated a few times with names of different member variables.

Can someone kind teach me how to initialize please? The header file cannot be changed. Only allowed changing of cpp file. However for cpp file, main function cannot be changed.

This first code is for header file. This is not allowed to be changed

```
class DiscreteGBM
{
    protected: 
       double r;              // risk free interest rate
       double S0;            // stock price at time 0
       double sigma;         // volatility
       double delta;         // length of time steps
       int numberSteps;      // total number of time steps; 
                             // start time is 0, end time is numberSteps*delta
    public:
        DiscreteGBM() {}
        void SetRiskFreeRate(double r1);            // set r to r1
        void SetInitialStockPrice(double s);        // set S0 to s
        void SetVolatility(double s);               // set sigma to s
        void SetTimeStepSize(double d);             // set delta to d
        void SetNumberSteps(int n);                 // set numberSteps to n
        vector<double> PricePath() const;           // compute price path S_0,...,S_T (where T=delta*n)
                                                    // according to formula (1) in the instructions,
                                                    // and return the vector (S_0,...,S_T)
};


// class for simulation of European call and put options
class EuropeanOption : public DiscreteGBM
{
    protected:
        bool callPut;    // callPut =0 if object is call option, callPut=1 if it's a put option
        double strike;   // strike price of option
    public:
        EuropeanOption() {}
        void SetCallPut(bool c);                     // set callPut to c
        void SetStrike(double s);                    // set strike to s
        double Payoff(double S_T) const;             // return payoff of option according to
                                                     // formulas (2) and (3) of the instructions;
                                                     // S_T is the stock price at maturity
        double BlackScholesPrice() const;            // return Black Scholes price of the option
                                                     // according to formulas (4) and (6) of the instructions

        double MonteCarloPrice(int numberScenarios=10000) const; 
                                                     // execute algorithm Monte Carlo pricing given 
                                                     // in instructions      
};
```

CPP file below

```
#include "Functions.h"
#include "PricingSimulation.h"


void DiscreteGBM::SetRiskFreeRate(double r1) {
    r = r1;
}

void DiscreteGBM::SetInitialStockPrice(double s) {
    S0 = s;
}

void DiscreteGBM::SetVolatility(double s) {
    sigma = s;
}

void DiscreteGBM::SetTimeStepSize(double d) {
    delta = d;
}

void DiscreteGBM::SetNumberSteps(int n) {
    numberSteps = n;
}

vector<double> DiscreteGBM::PricePath() const {
    vector<double> stock;
    vector<double> rnorm;
    rnorm = randn(numberSteps);
    stock[0] = S0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberSteps; i++) {
        stock[i] = stock[i - 1] * exp((r - 0.5 * sigma * sigma) * delta + sigma * sqrt(delta) * rnorm[i]);
    }
    return stock;
}

void EuropeanOption::SetCallPut(bool c) {
    callPut = c;
}

void EuropeanOption::SetStrike(double s) {
    strike = s;
}

double EuropeanOption::Payoff(double S_T) const {
    double value;
    if (callPut == 0)
        if ((S_T - strike) > 0)
            value = S_T - strike;
        else
            value = 0;
    else
        if ((strike - S_T) > 0)
            value = strike - S_T;
        else
            value = 0;
    return value;
}

double EuropeanOption::BlackScholesPrice() const {
    double value2, d1, d2;
    d1 = (1 / (sigma * sqrt(numberSteps * delta)) * (log(S0 / strike) + (r + sigma * sigma / 2) * numberSteps * delta));
    d2 = d1 - sigma * sqrt(numberSteps * delta);
    if (callPut == 0)
        value2 = normcdf(d1) * S0 - normcdf(d2) * strike * exp(-r * numberSteps * delta);
    else
        value2 = -normcdf(-d1) * S0 + normcdf(-d2) * strike * exp(-r * numberSteps * delta);
    return value2;
}

double EuropeanOption::MonteCarloPrice(int numberScenarios = 10000) const {
    int N = numberScenarios;
    double sum;
    double T = numberSteps * delta;
    vector <double> A;
    double O;
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        A = PricePath();
        O = A[numberSteps];
        sum += O;
    }
    double average = sum / N;
    return exp(-r * T) * average;
}

int main()
{
    SetSeed();
    EuropeanOption Test;
    for (double r = -0.1; r <= 0.1; r += 0.05)
        for (double sigma = 0.1; sigma <= 1; sigma += 0.3)
            for (int c = 0; c <= 1; c++)
            {
                Test.SetRiskFreeRate(r);
                Test.SetInitialStockPrice(100);
                Test.SetVolatility(sigma);
                Test.SetNumberSteps(100);
                Test.SetTimeStepSize(0.1);
                Test.SetStrike(130);
                Test.SetCallPut(c);
                cout << "r = " << r << ", sigma = " << sigma;
                cout << ", c = " << c << ": ";
                cout << Test.BlackScholesPrice() << " , ";
                cout << Test.MonteCarloPrice() << endl;
            }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: The message means exactly what it says. You cannot avoid it if you cannot change the header.

Comment: sorry to trouble you, if i can change the header file, how should I change it?

Comment: To avoid the message you need to initialise all member variables in every constructor.